# Splitting string of email addresses into different columns using the next available row

Tags: vba, excel, email, split

I need some help separating a string of email address that I pull from a spreadsheet.  I have a sheet set up so when you press the send notification button, the code looks for a number in a set column and if that number is equal to `1` or `2` it pulls the email address from column 4 and inserts it into the "To" field of an email.  I would like to log all of those email addresses using the split feature but I keep getting only the first email address and nothing further.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strto As String, strcc As String, strbcc As String
Dim strsub As String, strbody As String
Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
Dim sTo As String
Dim sCC As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim Y As Variant

Set emailRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D500")

For Each cl In emailRng


    If cl.Offset(, 68) = 1 Then sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value


    If cl.Offset(, 68) = 2 Then sCC = sCC & ";" & cl.Value

Next cl

sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)
sBCC = Mid(sCC, 2)


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strto = sTo
strcc = sCC
strbcc = ""
strsub = "'NOTIFICATION'  - " & Sheet9.Cells(1, 72).Value
strbody = "<img src=Z:\Logo2.jpg width=624 height=74>" & _
          "<font size=2 font face=Verdana color=black>"


With OutMail

    .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    .to = strto
    .cc = strcc
    .bcc = strbcc
    .Subject = strsub
    .importance = 2
    'You can add a file to the mail like this
    .HTMLBody = strbody
    .Display    ' or use .Send

End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
x = Split(sTo, "")


 Y = Split(sCC, "")

     lrtag = Sheets("Log Sheet").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Sheets("Log Sheet").Cells(lrtag + 1, "B").Value = "NOTIFICATION SENT"
      Sheets("Log Sheet").Cells(lrtag + 1, "C").Value = "DATE SENT"
      Sheets("Log Sheet").Cells(lrtag + 1, "D").Value = Now
      Sheets("Log Sheet").Cells(lrtag + 1, "E").Value = "NOTIFICATION SENT TO:"
      Sheets("Log Sheet").Cells(lrtag + 1, "F").Value =Application.Transpose(x)

 Sheets("HEADER").Select

 Unload Me

 End Sub
```

I think I need to expand the statement:

`Sheets("Log Sheet").Cells(lrtag + 1, "F").Value =Application.Transpose(x)`

Comment: You're splitting on an empty string - did you mean to split on `;`  ?

Comment: No, I want to split my x and y values starting on the next available row in column F and have them carry on in new columns going out as far as possible.  There could be 60+ email addresses in one email.

Comment: Also seems to be a typo here: `sBCC = Mid(sCC, 2)`

Comment: oh good catch, thank you.  that should be sCC = Mid(sCC, 2) correct?

Comment: I would guess so, yes.

Comment: I guess I didn't read your first comment correctly, I did forget to add the ';' to split the string

Comment: See my point below as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Transpose if you're placing a single-dimension array in a row, but you do need to specify the full range for the destination:

```
Sheets("Log Sheet").Cells(lrtag + 1, "F").Resize(1,ubound(x)+1).Value = x
```

You'd need to use Transpose if you wanted the array to go vertically.